# Can't format external drive

Tags: debian, disk, mkfs

I am trying to format an external drive, but getting the error

```
/dev/sdb1 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!
```

Based on the internet, I have to

run `cat /proc/mounts`:

```
/dev/sda3 /media/backup fusebl w,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
/dev/sdc1 /media/movies ext3 rw,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,nodelalloc,data=ordered 0 0
```

run `mount`:

```
/dev/sda3 on /media/backup type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdc1 on /media/movies type ext3 (rw,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,nodelalloc,data=ordered)
```

Also `fuser -v dev/sdb1` and nothing is using it.

I don't know what else to check to see why this is still in use.

I was able to run cfdisk on it, and remove the old (NTFS) partition and add a new one, but still cannot format.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that it is the right device you want to format, did you tried:
`umount -fl /dev/sdb1` ? What do you use to format?

Comment: result of `umount -fl /dev/sdb1` is `umount: /dev/sdb1: not mounted` I used `sudo mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdb1` and the result again was `/dev/sdb1 is apparently in...`

Answer (score 1):

1) Disconnect the drive, wait a few seconds, plug it back in, then try again
2) If 1 fails, reboot, then try again (right away, without using a file explorer)

Sometimes, using a file explorer (like Nautilus or Dolphin) locks the drive. One of the above usually fixes it.

Comment: I can try to disconnect, but this is a remote (basement) headless system and I am trying to do everything remotly

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark your question as "answered."